# Interactive geographic region definitions

Tags: postgis, export, web-mapping, software-recommendations, boundless-suite

### Background

An organization has regions within a province, but has no list of coordinates that define region boundaries. I would like to draw custom polygon areas on a map using a web-based and user-friendly interface (such as [Google My Maps](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/mymapstoolbar.html) or [Scribble Maps](http://scribblemaps.com/)). The regions are for data aggregation.

### Technical

[Maptitude](http://www.caliper.com/maptovu.htm) and [OpenGeo](http://opengeo.org/) are being considered for the final [GIS application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24185/data-visualization-and-maintenance-tool). The database will likely be PostgreSQL running PostGIS.

### Question

What open-source tool would you use to define the coordinates by drawing polygons on an interactive map? That is:

```
Browser -> Map -> Polygons (shared boundaries) -> Export
```

If the export step (to PostGIS) was performed automatically, so much the better.

A cross-browser solution (IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari) with a working demo would be most helpful.

### Related Links

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325670/draw-polygon-using-mouse-on-google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenLayers to provide your user with a simple editting toolbar.  Look [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/editingtoolbar.html) for a working example.

Look [here](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/oledit.html) for a tutorial with a bit more explanation on the hook up between your server and OL.  Alternatively, if you want an all-in environment you could consider [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/).  There isn't space to go into it here but there are a lot of good tutorials on the GeoDjango website that will show you how to have an interactive, editable environment.

Comment: Thanks, Sylvester. 1. Bug-ridden example: http://i.imgur.com/B2fEZ.png 2. Looking for an existing tool (such as Scribble Maps): no coding required (install and go). 3. This is part of a bigger project, where Python cannot be used as part of the technology stack.